# Get running processes using JNA

Tags: java, winapi, process, jna

I am trying to obtain a list of all currently running processes on a windows machine.

I am trying it with winapi calls via JNA to
  EnumProcesses -> OpenProcess -> GetModuleBaseNameW -> CloseHandle
It fails at the OpenProcess call. GetLastError returns 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED).

This is my code:

```
public static final int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;
public static final int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;
public static final int PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020;
public static final int PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008;


public interface Psapi extends StdCallLibrary {
    Psapi INSTANCE = (Psapi) Native.loadLibrary("Psapi", Psapi.class);

    boolean EnumProcesses(int[] ProcessIDsOut, int size, int[] BytesReturned);

    DWORD GetModuleBaseNameW(Pointer hProcess, Pointer hModule, byte[] lpBaseName, int nSize);

}

public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("Kernel32", Kernel32.class);

    Pointer OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, boolean bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    boolean CloseHandle(Pointer hObject);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] processlist = new int[1024];
    int[] dummylist = new int[1024];
    Psapi.INSTANCE.EnumProcesses(processlist, 1024, dummylist);

    for (int pid : processlist) {
        System.out.println(pid);
        Pointer ph = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pid);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }

        System.err.println(com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError()); // <- 5
        System.err.println(ph); // <- null
        if (ph != null) {
            byte[] filename = new byte[512];
            Psapi.INSTANCE.GetModuleBaseNameW(ph, new Pointer(0), filename, 512);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }

            System.err.println(Native.toString(filename));
            Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(ph);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Note that JNA includes a platform library which wraps many WinAPI calls already, so you'd have to do less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `OpenProcess` with `PROCESS_VM_READ` means that you want to read the memory of that process.  To do this, you need the `SE_DEBUG_PRIVLEGE`.  Your application doesn't have that privilege which is why you are getting access denied.

Check the MSDN article for [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  There is some community content on how to acquire that privilege.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I found out that I can read the memory of processes that belong to the current user, this is sufficient for me.