# How to use Java Native Access to set process affinity for processes besides Java.exe?

Tags: java, windows, jna, affinity

Although it is fairly easy to do manually, I am attempting to automate the setting of cpu affinity in Windows 7 for various VMs after their initial creation time. The project is in Java and I am trying to avoid directly including C code, so I have been using Java Native Access, which masks things like winapi. I'm new to the library, and it's a bit lacking in tutorials or examples, although there are some basic ones findable through quick Google searches.

Using the following code, I can set the affinity of the main Java process (ffffffffffffffff locally), but other processes remain completely unaffected, even when I have the privileges to manually set affinity using Task Manager. I have also iterated over all integers from 0 to 10000, rather than just entering ids I know to be valid.

Main class:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE;

public class SetAffinity {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int pid = -1;
    AffinityKernel instance = (AffinityKernel)Native.loadLibrary("Kernel32",AffinityKernel.class));
    System.out.println(instance.SetProcessAffinityMask(new HANDLE(new Pointer(pid)), 1));
  }
}
```

Utility interface:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE;

public interface AffinityKernel extends Kernel32{
  public boolean SetProcessAffinityMask(HANDLE hProcess, int dwProcessAffinityMask);
}
```

Since I can check that it correctly sets the cpu affinity of the process it's running in, I know the syntax is correct.

The question is:

How do I access/reference processes besides the current process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other routine you're looking for is [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx), which allows you to get a HANDLE to another process, which you can then use in the `SetProcessAffinityMask`. The calling signature:

```
HANDLE OpenProcess(DWORD dwDesiredAccess, BOOL bInheritHandle, DWORD dwProcessId);
```

It's exposed in the Kernel32 interface already.

Determining the process id of the other java processes using JNA [has been asked already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667557/get-running-processes-using-jna), and should be understandable.

Comment: OpenProcess is what I was missing. Thanks for the help!